# Is there a way to combine List.Contains() and string.StartsWith()?

Tags: c#

I have a list of filenames where i want to check if there are duplicate filenames different extensions

Example:
Randomfilename.xlsx and Randomfilename.pptx

My approach looks like this:

```
string tempFileName = originalFilename.Remove(file.LastIndexOf("."));
if (allFilesInDirectory.Contains(  string that starts with tempFileName  ))
```

But i dont think there is this exact function. Whats the workaround to this?

Comment: Use Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension().

Comment: If you want to check for other files with the same name but a different extension, you should probably leave the dot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ `Any` function

```cs
allFilesInDirectory.Any(s => s.StartsWith(tempFileName))
```

Or if you want to find the element

```cs
var file = allFilesInDirectory.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StartsWith(tempFileName));
```

**EDIT**

Without LINQ

```cs
allFilesInDirectory.FindAll(s => s.StartsWith(tempFileName)).Count > 0
```

or

```cs
var fileName = allFilesInDirectory.Find(s => s.StartsWith(tempFileName));
```

Comment: I think this will result in a false positive by finding the original file name itself.

Comment: Okay, he can use `FirstOrDefault` function for this approach

Comment: `List` has this functionality built in though, as `FindAll()`. Doesn't need Linq.

Comment: And to avoid the issue of matching `tempFileName` itself, you can just check on `.Count > 1`.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
var filenamesGrouped = allFilesInDirectory.GroupBy(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x));
var duplicates = filenamesGrouped.Count() > 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use LINQ here to group all files with the same filename, and filter groups with more than one duplicate filename:

```
var duplicates = Directory
    .GetFiles(path)
    .GroupBy(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f))
    .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1);
```

The above uses [`Directory.GetFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8) to list the files in a directory, [`Enumerable.GroupBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8) to group the files without the extension, which can be extracted with [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=netframework-4.8). Then you can filter the groups with [`Enumerable.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8).

**Demo:**

```
var duplicates = Directory
    .GetFiles(path)
    .GroupBy(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f))
    .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1);

foreach (var fileGroup in duplicates)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{fileGroup.Key} : {string.Join(", ", fileGroup.Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f)))}");
}
```

**Output:**

```
Randomfilename : Randomfilename.csv, Randomfilename.txt
```

If you want to check against a specific filename like in your question:

```
var duplicates = Directory
    .GetFiles(path)
    .Where(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f) == "Randomfilename");

if (duplicates.Count() > 1)
{
    // We found duplicates
}
```

Which we can wrap into a method as well:

```
private static bool FileHasDuplicates(string path, string filename)
{
    return Directory
        .GetFiles(path)
        .Where(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f) == filename)
        .Count() > 1;
}
```

If you want to scan all sub directories of a given directory as well, then you can use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.8):

```
var duplicates = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .GroupBy(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f))
    .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can sort `allFilesInDirectory` and iterate. Check for elements next to each other in the sorted list for matching file names (without extension).